# asp.net User not authenticated after successful login and redirect to homepage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have ASP.NET website that hosted on shared web hosting
my issue user login using correct username and password and the server redirect the user after success login to another page but after redirect user showing not signed and user must sign in again and keep not working without any error

i am using vb.net and i new to web developing

i have already tried restarting hosting server and it work but after while it stuck again

```
   Protected Sub LogIn(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Try


        If IsValid Then
            ' Validate the user password
            Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()
            Dim signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationSignInManager)()

            ' This doen't count login failures towards account lockout
            ' To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout := True
            Dim result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout:=False)

            Select Case result
                Case SignInStatus.Success
                    IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"), Response)
                    Exit Select
                Case SignInStatus.LockedOut
                    Response.Redirect("/Account/Lockout")
                    Exit Select
                Case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification
                    Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Account/TwoFactorAuthenticationSignIn?ReturnUrl={0}&RememberMe={1}",
                                                    Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"),
                                                    RememberMe.Checked),
                                      True)
                    Exit Select
                Case Else
                    FailureText.Text = "Invalid login attempt"
                    ErrorMessage.Visible = True
                    Exit Select
            End Select
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        FailureText.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Please share your code so we can see what you are working with

Comment: whats part of code you want ? i edit my question and i added login code

Comment: what's going on in the page it redirects to

Comment: redirects to home page or login page again

Comment: put a break point and follow it down, what case statement is it falling into on both loads?

Comment: On my pc its working fine but after i publish my site it stop working after few moments

Comment: Then it could be many things, check any config files on the server. Tmeouts/authentication settings etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solve my issue with login by deleting every reportviewer from all pages